# call a function using requirejs

Tags: html, requirejs

How do I call a function using requirejs?

It's an overly simple question, but surprisingly enough no tutorial or example has been able to help me so far.

This is the code in my html file.

```
...
<script src = "stuff.js"></script>
<button onclick="doStuff(4, 2)";>DoStuff</button>
...
```

This is my require js.

```
define(["jquery"], function ($) {
  function doStuff(a, b) {
    //does some stuff
  }
});
```

Why does this not work? I get
ReferenceError: doStuff is not defined

Comment: `doStuff` will only exist within the scope of the require callback. The reason there's no tutorial on it is because you shouldn't be adding this sort of dependency in inline event handlers. Keep your JS out of your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution for the question by passing the function into the html code. It's not very elegant, but it works.

**index.html**

```
<button onclick = "doSomeStuff(4,2);">DoStuff</button>
<script>
  require(['stuff.min'], function(myStuff){
    function doSomeStuff(a,b) {
      myStuff.doStuff(a,b);
    }
  });
</script>
```

**stuff.js**

```
define(["jquery"], function ($) {
  function doStuff(a,b) {
    //does some stuff
  }
  return {doStuff:doStuff};
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your immediate problem could be something like this:

**index.html**

```
<button id="the-button">DoStuff</button>
<script data-main="stuff" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

**stuff.js**

```
require(["jquery"], function ($) {
  function doStuff(a, b) {
    //does some stuff
  }

  $('#the-button').click(function() {
    doStuff(4, 2);
  });
});
```

But it looks like you would benefit from taking a step back and reading about modern JavaScript architecture and techniques. This should be a good starting point: [Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871640/1240557)

Comment: Thank you, however I can't do this in my actual work as I dynamically create the functions in my html.

Comment: Which benefit or RequireJS made you decide to use it, then? It's *a bit* unreasonable to expect a technology that's essentially all about adding structure to JS apps to support such an outdated and deprecated architecture (i.e. mixing HTML and JS).

Comment: User's browser still downloads all the code, that's an inherent feature of client-side Javascript. RequireJS is not going to help you, Chrome's or FF's dev tools make it easier and easier to navigate through any page's code (and even change it on the fly). The best thing you can do if you're concerned with security is to prepare for it.

Comment: Yes, but requireJS caches faster. I ended up finding a way to dynamically create my functions, declaring them inside of other functions. Thank you all.

Comment: I ran into this problem as well there is some dynamic content that gets loaded as I generate the page, that I can't possibly know in the future. The problem is RequireJS is trying to load in a synchronous dependency way. If you load stuff inline after then it has potential to load out of sync. My solution is to put information in div tags and then select based on that. Similar to how BootstrapJS works.